# Populate the most recent date for value in corresponding column

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

First post, Im a bit stumped here.  I am creating an availability tracker for workers that also tracks the last time they performed a duty.  J2:2 are the date cells and rows 4 and up list the last time one of several functions was performed.  Each row is one worker.  I am trying to find a way for sheets to see only the most recent day prior to the current day that the duty “LM”shows up for each worker and populate the corresponding date from J2:2 in column F4:F.  Ill try to find a way to link my project here.

[Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LjG4.png)

Tried a bunch.  Closest i got was what you see in the picture, but it uses text join and gives me all of the occurrences rather than just the most recent.

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Answer (score 0):

What about the following one-

```
 =INDEX(FILTER(J2:2,J4:4="LM"),,2)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, I over thought this one huh?  Seems to work.  I’ll play around with it more tomorrow.  Thank you good sir, you saved my few remaining hairs.

Comment: The only issue I see is it pulls the last “lm” instead of the most recent prior to the current day.

Comment: @matthewschellinger Would please clarify what do you mean by most recent? You may need `SORT()` function.

Comment: Sure. I need the date closest to but not greater than the current day.  That is, the day you are viewing the sheet.

Comment: So what I am tracking is currency.  A worker may only perform the lm job if they have already done it in the last 60 days.   So the sheet must pull the most recent date in j2:2 that is prior to the date that you look at the sheet on.  The column next to the one I am trying to do this in adds 60 days and gives me the expiration date of the workers currency.